# Como capturar el src de una imagen con código jquery

Tags: jquery

Por favor estoy necesitando un código jquery que me capture el varlor src = "foto_perfil/foto.jpg" (como muestra la imagen abajo).

He intentado con este código:

```
var id = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").find("img").eq(7).attr("src");
alert(id);
```

Pero me sale indefinido. Por favor alguien me puede orientar de otra manera. Muchas gracias..

Para fernando torres: Como hago para colocarle data-id si el código html que adjunte a la pregunta es dinámico, tiene que cambiar por el bucle. Pregunta para fernando Torrres?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `$("img[title='Foto Perfil']").attr('src')` Prueba con esto a ver que tal

Comment: Añade el código del `html` en la pregunta por favor. Algunos usuarios pueden tener problemas para ver las imagenes y ademas es mucho mas sencillo para todo el mundo tener el código que tratar y no una imagen.

Comment: Tengo una tabla dinámica con muchos registros, necesito es recorrer todos y capturar el correspondiente a la fila. Muchas gracias de todas maneras

Answer (score 3):

Si solo tienes una etiqueta `<img>` en tu tabla puedes obtener el `src` con esto:

```
let valor_src= $("#mitabla img").attr("src");
```

Resultado:

```
foto_perfil_foto.jpg
```

**EDIT**

Si tienes muchas imágenes, lo cual no especificaste en tu pregunta inicial pero sí en tu comentario después de mi respuesta, vas a tener que identifícalas con un número único, éste va ir como atributo en la etiqueta `<img>` al cual le llamaremos `data-id` y una clase que compartirá cada etiqueta a la que llamaremos `mi-imagen`, ejemplo:

Tu lista de imágenes:

```
<td><img src="ijk.jpg" data-id="1" class="mi-imagen"></td>
<td><img src="abc.jpg" data-id="2" class="mi-imagen"></td>
<td><img src="def.jpg" data-id="3" class="mi-imagen"></td>
<td><img src="geh.jpg" data-id="4" class="mi-imagen"></td>
```

Si quieres obtener el `src` de la imagen con `data-id=4` usarías:

```
let valor_src = $('.mi-imagen[data-id="4"]').attr("src");
```

El resultado del anterior código `javascript` sería el siguiente:

```
geh.jpg
```

El elemento CSS es el que hace la magia puesto que vas a traer un elemento con la clase `mi-imagen` que a la vez cumple con la condición de tener un atributo llamado `data-id` con valor de `4`. Básicamente esta es la lógica.

Saludos.

Comment: Tiengo varias etiquetas en la tabla. Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor ve mi actualización de la respuesta